# Get div to shrink before it jumps down

Tags: html, css, styling

I have two divs along side each other. Both containing a table each. The one on the left is smaller than the one on the right.

First of all i want the one on the right to take as much space as possible without making the left div jump down. Also. i want this right div to become smaller with the window size untill it cannot get smaller, where it will then jump down.

What happens now, is that the div right first jumps down, and then shrinks as the window becomes smaller. I want to first shrink all it can, and after that if the window becomes smaller, it jumps down.

Hope you can get what I am taling about:

```
<div id="left">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Content here is not so wide</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Big table with lots of columns</td>
            <td>Big table with lots of columns</td>
            <td>Big table with lots of columns</td>
            <td>Big table with lots of columns</td>
            <td>Big table with lots of columns</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put both elements in container with display:flex;

Then you'll be able to set width for first element and flex the other for the maximum width. Also add minimal-width for the second element.

Finally, you'll want to display both elements as inline-block so when second elements gets to small it'll jump down.

Comment: As a warning, display:flex support isn't the greatest. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox